# TFS Build is canceled after some seconds running

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, vstest

I have a TFS build with VSTest task that always get cancelled automatically after some seconds.

I downloaded the build logs and i got ZERO errors.

Is there any condition that can abort a build with no error logs?

I use a TestSettings file that has timeouts configured: 
[image]

The TFS build duration is also set:

[image: build config]

but the test task is canceled with a minute:

[image]

Comment: Does this issue happen on a particular project or all projects? You may create a light test project to see whether you would get the same issue, so that we can indicate the issue is from TFS side or your project side.

Comment: Hi Cece, This occurs within a particular BUILD. Other builds at same project (even with other test tasks) runs ok at the same build agent.

Comment: It seems the issue is from your test project setting. How about run this project locally?

Comment: The test run occurs normally locally. I selected only 3 tests to try at build agent, locally these 3 tests, or all tests runs normally without being cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. 
This test have this configuration at TestSettings file:

```
  <DataCollectors>
    <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/HttpProxy/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.HttpProxyCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and Test Impact">
    </DataCollector>   </DataCollectors>
```

Removing this from the test settings solved the problem.

I cannot investigate the root cause (why its cancelled with this configuration without any error message)